# registry changes not being retained after reboot

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-registry

My Windows 7 user account is an administrator.

In regedit, I remove some entries from HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

After I reboot, the entries are back again.

The entries I remove are:

- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrotray.exe"
- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat_sl.exe"
- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Creative Cloud\ACC\Creative Cloud.exe" --showwindow=false -- - onOSstartup=true
- "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\APSDaemon.exe"
- "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunesHelper.exe"
- "C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTTask.exe" -atboottime

I have Zone Alarm, AVG AV, and Microsoft Security Essentials installed. I have no other system utilities installed.

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you removing?

Comment: An annoying number of programs set themselves or related programs to run on boot-up whenever they are scheduled: the registry entries should give you a good clue as to which they are. If you're lucky there may be a "Start with Windows" option you can disable. Otherwise, you can edit the entries so nothing is launched and protect their permissions against overwriting. Or you can use SysInternals' Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out what is writing the entries.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've added the entries that I try to remove.